# Replace svn repository with an archive

Tags: svn

Is there a simple way to replace a svn repository with a archived dump?

I have a foo.tar that contains the future version of a svn repository. To commit this to the svn repository, all I need to do is to overwrite with the contents of foo.tar and svn delete all files not in foo.tar and then commit?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You're talking about `svn delete` and `commit`. Those terms indicate you have an svn *[working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc)* at hand, and not a *[repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.basic.repository.html)*. Could you clarify which one you mean?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm on a working copy and not the centralized repository. However, I have access to central repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple delete with Explorer will not actually delete files in repository. Deleting all files with svn may be an overkill. I would set dates of all files in WC to some null-date, then copy all files from tar, then find and delete with svn all files that retained their null-date.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a good approach. I'm also uncertain how svn will handle an "svn delete" and then the file gets overwritten? Ideally it should handle it as a modification, but I'm uncertain if it's clever enough or if it will handle it as a delete and add?

Comment: I use TortoiseSVN for my svn operations, so my guesses may be wrong, but... When a file is deleted with svn it does not exist in WC anymore. The file you see there is now just some ordinary file. It makes no difference if it is modified, unmodified, deleted, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no **real** better way to do it.

- Checkout your project
- Delete all files in explorer (keep .svn folders and content)
- Extract your archive in this folder
- Check every file/folder and commit

Note :
Added item will be marked as added if you check them.
Removed item will be marked as removed if you check them (reported as missing).

Comment: Hi! I understand everything except what do you mean by "check every file/folder and commit"?

Comment: Once you open the commit panel, you check all files/folder. So you clic in the checkboxes ;) This will add new files and delete missing files.

Comment: Okay, I think you must be using some visual tool. I'm using the svn tool from command line so not sure what that means there :) Thanks!